# ReportGenerator HtmlChart Report Output Usage

Tags: reportgenerator

I have been looking at the HtmlChart report in order to produce a report that shows the history of code coverage for a project.  I have generated a few yyyy-mm-dd_hh-mm-ss_CoverageHistory.xml files that are stored in a directory indicated by the -historydir option.  When I run the reportgenerator command, I am requesting the following report types: Cobertura;HtmlChart. There is output in the console saying each of the history files have been parsed; however, the CoverageHistory.html report only has data from the first xml file.

In looking at the CoverageHistory.xml files, there is one "coverage" node in each of the files - is this correct?  Should each of these files be aggregated in the HtmlChart report and included as a separate point in the chart based on the date in the CoverageHistory.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One node in each coverage file is absolutely correct.
The chart only shows any additional points if there's any change in coverage, otherwise the elements are merged together.
So maybe you add another test, which increases coverage, then you should see another point in the chart.